# Using Closure::bind in a child class

Tags: php, closures

I'm trying to use [this trick](http://ocramius.github.io/blog/accessing-private-php-class-members-without-reflection) to access a private variable of a base class from a child class, but I don't fully understand closures, so I'm having issues.  The following example almost works, except that I'm binding to a new instance of the parent class instead of the child class' instance.

```
class Kitchen
{
    private $yummy = 'cake';

    public function change_treat()
    {
        $yummy = 'pie';
    }
}

class pantry extends Kitchen
{


    public function FindFood()
    {

        $yum = function ()
        {
            return $this->yummy;
        };

        $kit = new Kitchen();
        $yumers = Closure::bind($yum, $kit, $kit);
        echo "Look, a " . $yumers(). "!\n";
    }
}

$p = new pantry();
$p->FindFood();
$p->change_treat();
$p->FindFood();
```

Output:

```
Look, a cake!
Look, a cake!
```

Desired Output:

```
Look, a cake!
Look, a pie!
```

I understand why my code outputs `cake` twice.  It's because I create an entirely separate Kitchen object when I bind the closure. What I'm having trouble with is figuring out what to pass into `closure::bind` to say "bind to my parent" or if what I'm doing is even possible.  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

**Edit:** For those of you who shared your concern about this technique, I understand that this breaks encapsulation and is not recommended.  For now, this is a proof of concept.  The situation is that I have a Wordpress plugin that has functionality that I'd like to extend. This part of the plugin has no hooks so I'm trying to find other ways to extend it.  One of the variables is private and I need to check it to determine whether to call the parent method or to use my custom logic.  I know that this sounds dubious, and I will treat this as a "gum and duct tape" endeavor. I am planning on reporting to  the plugin developer what I've tried and what could make the plugin easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is wrong here:

```
public function change_treat()
{
    $yummy = 'pie';
}
```

It should be:

```
public function change_treat()
{
    $this->yummy = 'pie';
}
```

Otherwise, you'd just be assigning a value to a function-local variable, which gets discarded when its done.

Secondly, at every call to `pantry::FindFood()` you create a new `Kitchen` instance which you then bind the closure to.

The way you could solve this is by breaking the inheritance chain:

```
class pantry
{
    private $kitchen;

    function __construct(Kitchen $kitchen)
    {
        $this->kitchen = $kitchen;
    }

    function findFood()
    {
        $yum = function() {
            return $this->yummy;
        };

        $kit = new Kitchen();
        $yumers = Closure::bind($yum, $this->kitchen, $this->kitchen);
        echo "Look, a " . $yumers(). "!\n";
    }
}

$k = new Kitchen();
$p = new pantry($k);

$p->FindFood();
$k->change_treat();
$p->FindFood();
```

That said, it's better not to use this hack at all and fix the `Kitchen` classby adding a getter, e.g. `getYummy()`.

Comment: Correcting this mistake [still doesn't work](http://3v4l.org/MP3Ub). However, using reflection [does](http://3v4l.org/U0R2X) (although the main point still stands: please don't do this)

Comment: This works if you use Closure::bind($yum, $this->kitchen, $this->kitchen);.  I edited the post to reflect this.  I will see if this works in my scenario and accept it if it does.

Comment: @VanillaBean Right, that's what I meant to write, actually :)

Comment: @Jack I should have realized this sooner but I need to override a method in the parent class and check the private variable from there.  So composition won't work.  I need inheritance.

Comment: @DaveRandom Your reflection example does exactly what I needed, so I'll use that.  (I know the whole point of the article I linked to was to **not** use reflection, but for my purposes, it's probably good enough.  I didn't pursue that route because, well, I was lazy. :)  If you create an answer, I'll accept it.)

Comment: You can add `__call()` to pretend inheritance safe for an actual `instanceof` test.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that creating a new Kitchen if FindFood means that I'll get pie and that part is wrong. What I'm asking, is, what do I pass to closure::bind to bind to the parent Kitchen instance instead of the Pantry instance.

## revised answer:

In your code example, the closure *does* bind to the instance of `Kitchen` you create in `FindFood`.  That's where you get the value "cake".  When you call `change_treat`, you are changing the `$yummy` value in your `Pantry` object.  The value in the `Kitchen` object is unchanged.

```
<?php
class kitchen{

    private $_yummy = "cake";

    public function change_yummy( $newvalue ){
        $this->_yummy = $newvalue;
    }

    public function find_yummy(){
        return "Look, a {$this->_yummy}!";
    }
}
class pantry extends kitchen{

    public function __construct( kitchen $kitchen ){
        $this->_kitchen = $kitchen;
    }

    public function change_yummyInKitchen( $newvalue ){
        $closure = Closure::bind(
            function()use( $newvalue ){
                $this->change_yummy( $newvalue );
            },
            $this->_kitchen,
            "kitchen"
        );
        $closure();
    }
    public function find_yummyInKitchen(){
        $closure = Closure::bind(
            function(){
                return $this->find_yummy();
            },
            $this->_kitchen,
            "kitchen"
        );
        return $closure();
    }
}

$kitchen = new kitchen;
$pantry = new pantry( $kitchen );

print $pantry->find_yummy();           // prints "Look, a cake!"
print $pantry->find_yummyInKitchen();  // prints "Look, a cake!"

$pantry->change_yummy( "pie" );
print $pantry->find_yummy();           // prints "Look, a pie!"
print $pantry->find_yummyInKitchen();  // prints "Look, a cake!"

$pantry->change_yummyInKitchen( "pie" );
print $pantry->find_yummy();           // prints "Look, a pie!"
print $pantry->find_yummyInKitchen();  // prints "Look, a pie!"
```

Also, re-reading your question and comments, I think you might be misunderstanding what "parent" means.  It applies to the class definition, not to particular objects.  In your code example, `Kitchen` is `Pantry`'s parent class, but the *object* `$kit` you create inside your `Pantry` class *is not* the "parent" of your `$p` object.

There's a reason this is so complicated and inconvenient: things are not meant to work this way.  I understand that you already know that this breaks encapsulation, etc., and so I won't try to talk you out of it on those grounds.  But apart from being "best practice," re-working this idea would be *simpler* and *work better* with *fewer bugs*.

Comment: I wasn't very clear in what I need to accomplish.  I've edited the question to hopefully make it clearer.  I _meant_ to change $p.  What I want to do is change the scope to $p's parent class when I bind the closure.

Comment: You _are_ doing so.  That's exactly _why_ you never see the value "pie."  See edits above.  **Also**, see @Jack's answer below regarding your `change_treat` method (I missed that).

Comment: I know that creating a new Kitchen if FindFood means that I'll get pie and **that part is wrong**.  What I'm asking, is, what do I pass to closure::bind to bind to the parent Kitchen instance instead of the Pantry instance.